# Incorrect frame size with rotated CATextLayer

Tags: swift, core-animation

I'm struggling trying to understand how to draw a rotated and properly-sized CATextLayer. By properly-sized, I mean that the frame of the CATextLayer is sized to just fit the text.

In the example below, I'm trying to draw the number "12" rotated by 55 degrees (for reasons which will become obvious). textLayer is the CATextLayer. I'm colouring the background black just to visualize the frame. This code snippet gets called as part of layoutSubviews().

```
    print("configureTextLayer")

    textLayer.string = "12"
    textLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName("Futura-Medium" as CFString, 120.0, nil)  // fontSize seemingly ignored here
    textLayer.fontSize = CGFloat(120.0)
    textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter

    let frameSize = textLayer.preferredFrameSize()
    print("frameSize: \(frameSize)")

    textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)

    // Translate and rotate within superlayer, needs to be calculated based on number, hour|minute, size and appearance
    textLayer.position = CGPoint(x: layer.frame.width/2, y: layer.frame.height/2)  // centred at clock middle for debugging
    textLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(55.0), 0, 0, 1)
```

[image: 55 degree rotated "12" issue]

On application start,this code (i.e. layoutSubviews) gets called twice as can be seen in the console snippet below:

```
configureTextLayer
frameSize: (140.0, 160.0)
configureTextLayer
frameSize: (-50.0, 206.0)
```

Notice how the preferredFrameSize differs between calling. The first one seems correct. That is, it would fit the unrotated "12" perfectly. The second is taller and narrower (and negative width). That height is probably what you'd expect for the cartesian height of a 55-degree rotated 140x160 rectangle.

If I set my rotation to 90.0, I get the following:

[image: 90 degree rotated "12"]

and in the console:

```
configureTextLayer
frameSize: (140.0, 160.0)
configureTextLayer
frameSize: (-159.0, 140.0)
```

It almost seems to me that ...

... I was writing this sentence and had an epiphany ;-) Namely that on the second calling of this code, the transform from the previous call was still in effect. As a test, I inserted this line just before calling the preferredFrameSize method.

```
textLayer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
```

and voila, here's my 55 degree rotated "12" now:

[image: 55 degree rotated "12" with identity transform]

And now the console shows the expected:

```
configureTextLayer
frameSize: (140.0, 160.0)
configureTextLayer
frameSize: (140.0, 160.0)
```

I'm going to post this since I would like to know if this approach to text rotation makes sense. It seems like a lot of work to me ... but I'm brand new to Swift and iOS development so maybe this is just the way it is. And maybe someone else will stumble across this and it'll help them.

Cheers,
Darran.